# Reccurent sequence limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

$c>=0$

$a_1 = c$

$a_{n+1}=1+\frac{a_n}{a_n + 1}$

How can I calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ in dependency on $c$?

Comment: If $x:=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists, the recurrence tells us that $x=1+x/(x+1)$.

Comment: so the limit is 1, but how can I check if the limit exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $a_{n+1}=2-\frac{1}{a_n+1}$. Thus for every integer $n \ge 2$, $1<a_n<2$.

Also $a_{n+1} \ge a_n$ if and only if $\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\le a_n\le \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

If $c\le\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, $a_{n+1}=1+\frac{a_n}{a_n+1}\ge a_n$ is true, so by the Monotone Sequence Theorem the limit of the sequence exists.

If $c>\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, it means that $a_{n+1}<a_n$, so the given sequence decreases. By the Monotone Sequence Theorem, the limit of the sequence exists.

Now let the limit $L$, then $L=1+\frac{L}{L+1}$ gives $L=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ regardless of the choice of $c$.